# Problem deploying services on Axis2 under Glassfish 5

Tags: glassfish-5, axis2c

My previous configuration: OS: CentOS 5.6, Java: 1.6.0_45, Glassfish: 3, Axis2: 1.5.3

My new configuration: OS: Debian 10, Java: 1.8.0_151, Glassfish: 5, Axis2: 1.8.2

On my previous configuration, I used to deploy my services .class files in the axis2/WEB-INF/classes folder with a subfolder for each of my services.
And services.xml in the axis2/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF folder.

My services.xml looks like this:

```
<serviceGroup><service name="PostesPhysiques" ><description>Gestion des postes physiques</description><messageReceivers><messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" /><messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/></messageReceivers><parameter name="ServiceClass">postes_physiques.PostesPhysiquesService</parameter></service><service name="PostesVirtuels" ><description>Gestion des postes virtuels</description><messageReceivers><messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" /><messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/></messageReceivers><parameter name="ServiceClass">postes_virtuels.PostesVirtuelsService</parameter></service></serviceGroup>
```

Then after restarting the Glassfish domain, my services were visible on the Axis2 Services page.

On my new configuration, I do the same operations but my services are not visible on the Axis2 Services page.

For my new configuration, I compiled my java project with Eclipse Mars and Java 8.

Am I missing something?

After some research, I found that I had the services.xml file missing in the folder axis2\WEB-INF\services\services\META-INF of my new configuration.
Then I added it and now Axis2 tells me that I have a faulty service at /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/axis2/WEB-INF/services/services but when I click on the link it says "No services found in this location".

I just found something new, on the Axis2 Happiness Page over http I see the following...
Examining Version Service
Found Axis2 default Version service and Axis2 is working properly.

But over https, I see this...
Examining Version Service
There was a problem in Axis2 version service , may be the service not available or some thing has gone wrong. But this does not mean system is not working ! Try to upload some other service and check to see whether it is working.

Also, when I go to the Services page over https, I see this...
Internal server error